# How to control items in webkit context menu?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I am developing a webkit application for public release, and wondering how to deal with context menus.

The problem is there are items in Safari's default context menu that I don't want to show end users:

- Reload
- Inspect Element

Possibly others. So, question #1 is: **Is it possible to remove items selectively from the default context menu?**

Another option is to create my own context menu from scratch, but then comes a host of other problems:

- I lose default functionality, for example spell-checking on `textarea`s, or accessibility features.
- I lose OSX's system-wide context menu handling behavior, so it will be a less-native UI behavior. I suppose for this I could implement the menu in the native host application.

So the main question is in general, **What should I do to preserve default functionality in Safari's context menu, while restricting certain things like "reload", "Inspect Element"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use the WebUIDelegate protocol method?

```
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
```

You should be able to take the defaultItems, add the ones you want to keep to a new array, and then return said array?